# Mirror image of/in/over/across a line

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

What is the correct preposition to use in a sentence that describes how a mirror image is reflected through something? This is for mathematical use, and I am in doubt about two scenarios, here shown as example sentences:

- The mirror image of point (2,3) ***in*** the origin is (-2,-3).
- The mirror image of point (2,3) ***over*** the x-axis is (2,-3).

In the first example, a mathematical entity is being mirrored in a point, whereas it in the second example is being mirrored over a line.

Is `in` and `over` correctly used in these two examples? I wouldn't think so as I feel like guessing. Other suggestions than `in` and `over` might be `across`, `of`, `through` and the like. In my native Danish language I would say `in` for a point (Danish `i`) and `over` for a line (Danish `(hen)over`), thus my choice for the two shown example sentences.

What would correct prepositions be in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal favorite preposition for this type of expression, though it may be a bit old-fashioned, is "**about**": e.g., -(x^2) is the reflection/mirror image of x^2 about the X-axis. "Across" works, too, as do the suggestions in swmcdonnell's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you also use "about" in the case of a point?

Comment: Yep, wouldn't make a difference if it's a point or a set of points. It's just kind of weird to refer to a "mirror image" of a point, since there isn't much of an "image" there.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. Mathematically you can reflect a point about another point as you would reflect about a line through that point which is perpendicular to the line between the two points.

Answer (score 1):

The prepositions you suggested are used for possession, association and location. They don't apply here because you are comparing the point with something else.

I would use **with respect to**, **in relation to** or **relative to** to show that you're stating one object's location based on the location of the other object.

> The mirror image of point (2,3) **in relation to** the origin is (-2, -3).

> The mirror image of point (2,3) **with respect to** the x-axis is (2, -3).

and

> The mirror image of point (2,3) **relative to** the y-axis is (-2, 3).

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I understand your answer correctly, then I believe I must have been unclear with my question - my apologies for that. I am not referring to the point or line themselves being mirrored. Rather, I am referring to, say, some point being mirrored *in* a point and *over* a line. So I wouldn't expect possession to be the relevant characteristic here. I have updated the question with clearer example sentences.

Comment: I created a new answer based on your revised question.

Comment: @Steeven To say that "*some point [is] being mirrored in a point*" seems to me almost meaningless, and I have some training in both mathematics and physics. I suspect that you are referring to  a situation in which the lines of site all cross at a singel point, nd the image (perhspd inverted) is formed at a locuse twice as far from the object as the point is. If this is the intent, I would say the image is reflected **through** a  point"  or perhaps "is reflected **via** a point." Have I grasped your intention correctly? In any case I doi not think "in" can be the correct  word here.

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring indicates some type of image production in a directly-across type of transition. When you mirror in a surface, you change the sign of the dimension perpendicular to the surface. When you mirror in a point (as in your example) you change the sign of all dimensions.

Therefore, you can use several possible words. Each is acceptable and correct and means the same: in, over, on, through, across, and by are some of them. For example, "mirrored by the x-axis" would be correct, as would any of the other words used insted of "by."

"Mirrored of" would not be correct. Though you could say "the mirror image of point A=(x,y) through the y-axis is (x,-y)."

"Mirrored around" would be questionable since mirroring is not "around," because that indicates rotation. Mirroring is not rotation.

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mirror+image%22+%22through+the+axis%22) are many written contexts where "mirror image" and "**through** the axis" occur in close proximity. But as you say, we can use a range of prepositions here. There's no such thing as **the** "correct" preposition.